# What is the equivalent of Invoke("SetOption") in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols?

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, directoryservices

I have a legacy .NET library doing the following:

```cs
const int adsOptionPasswordMethod = 7;
const int adsPasswordEncodeClear = 0;
user.Invoke ("SetOption", new object[] { adsOptionPasswordMethod, adsPasswordEncodeClear });
```

I am using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` in .NET 7 now, and I want to do something like this:

```cs
const int adsOptionPasswordMethod = 7;
const int adsPasswordEncodeClear = 0;
var setOptionsAccountControl = new DirectoryAttributeModification
{
    Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace,
    Name = "SetOption",
};
modifyUserAccountControl.Add(adsOptionPasswordMethod);
modifyUserAccountControl.Add(adsPasswordEncodeClear);
```

But the above seems wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "seems wrong"? Have you tried it and it didn't work how you expected? Also, how are `modifyUserAccountControl`, `adsOptionPasswordMethod`, and `adsPasswordEncodeClear` defined in your second code block?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I have updated the code. The first block works. The second block fails with the following error: `The request attribute does not exist. 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090D77, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v2580.`

Comment: The `Name` parameter of `DirectoryAttributeModification` refers to the attribute you're trying to change. So it's complaining that there is no attribute called "SetOption".

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/ne-iads-ads_password_encoding_enum), the value of `ADS_PASSWORD_ENCODE_CLEAR` is `1`, but you're using `0`. Were you actually using `0` in your old application?

Comment: And is there a reason you're trying to send passwords in plain text rather than encrypted? Seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Right so how can I set options with the Protocols library? `DirectoryAttributeModification` seems to modify an attribute, not an option. Also, that is what the old code did, so I am just porting it over to .NET Core. My work must have a reason for doing it this way but I am not sure.

Comment: So was the old application using `0`? Because that means it was using SSL. Does the LDAP path include `:636` in the server name? If this code sets a password, then all you need to connect via SSL and you don't need to set those options at all. (which I can show you how to do)

Comment: @GabrielLuci I am able to successfully connect to LDAP using 636, I am able to successfully create a `DirectoryAttributeModification` to `userPassword` and change the users password. Everything works great. The only thing I cannot do is SetOption 7, to the value of 0. Which is what the old code did. From what I understand, setting 7 (PASSWORD_METHOD) to 0 (PASSWORD_ENCODE_REQUIRE_SSL) would simply require SSL when setting the password correct? Are you saying this is no longer needed?

Comment: If the purpose of that block of code is to change the password and you're able to do that without setting that option, then you're good!

Comment: Thanks @GabrielLuci if you want to type that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/ne-iads-ads_password_encoding_enum), the value of `ADS_PASSWORD_ENCODE_CLEAR` is `1`, but the old code is using `0`, which is the value for `ADS_PASSWORD_ENCODE_REQUIRE_SSL`, which requires the use of SSL.

So if the old code was working, then it must have already been connecting via SSL (port 636).

The [documentation for the `unicodePwd` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2) (the real attribute for the password, although [`userPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f3adda9f-89e1-4340-a3f2-1f0a6249f1f8) can work too) says that:

> servers require that the client have a 128-bit (or better) SSL/TLS-encrypted connection to the DC in order to modify this attribute.

If it's already using SSL, then that's all that's needed to be able to set the password. Setting those options isn't necessary.